# Java- EE 1.6 How to read MAC Addresses inside same Subnet

Tags: jakarta-ee, mac-address

I'm trying to read the Mac Address of a client inside my subnet ( but not on the same machine running my testServer application )

```
@ManagedBean
public class ManagedBeanController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3244711761400747261L;

private String hostMac;
private InetAddress hostIp;
private String tmpIp;

// snippet taken from a BalusC post , works great. just pointing out that 
// in case of a request from a client running on the same machine of the server, 
// it return 127.0.0.1 (lookpback) instead of the actual localhost IP
public ManagedBeanController() {    
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    tmpIp = request.getRemoteAddr();                            
}

public void ReadHostMac() 
{
    try {

        // InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); **COMMENTED**
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(tmpIp); 
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + address.getHostAddress() );
        System.out.println("Host NAME : " + address.getHostName() );

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);

        if ( network!=null ) 
        {
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            if ( mac != null ) 
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
                }

                System.out.println("Current MAC address : " + sb.toString());
                setHostMac(sb.toString());

            } 
            else
            {               
                System.out.println("MAC address NULL");
                setHostMac("MAC address NULL");
            }

        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

// getters and setters

}
```

what this Bean return is:
if in the code is used 
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
it only return the localhost Mac Address, no matter which client is connecting.
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(tmpIp);
  in this case the NETWORK properties is returned properly in case of a local call but not  the MAC properties, even worse from a "remote" (still inside the subnet tho) call, in that case even the NETWORK properties is returned as NULL.
any hints appreciated, thanks